# Why does this VBA Macro that copies and paste range into email in the wrong order?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a macro that will copy and paste a range into an email in outlook.  I have text and formatting that I would like to include below the range that is pasted in the email.

```
Sub sendEmailwithPic()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim table As Range
Dim pic As Picture
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wordDoc


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'grab table, convert to image, and cut
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set table = ws.Range("A1:E11")
ws.Activate
table.Copy
Set pic = ws.Pictures.Paste
pic.Cut

'create email message
On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "someone@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Country Population Data " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")
        .Display
        
        Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        wordDoc.Range.PasteandFormat wdChartPicture
        .HTMLBody = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc.</b></p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Calibri>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;color:#595959><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor." & _
                "Hendrerit dolor magna eget est.</i></font></p>" & .HTMLBody
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

When the macro compiles the email that is displayed looks like this:[image]

However, my desired outcome is this:
[image]

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I might be missing something here but your actual results are the same as your desired results

Comment: @CHill60 No they are different.  The actual results has the text on top of the image.  The desired have the text below the image.  I can’t figure out how to paste the image on top of the text.

Comment: Try to paste the content into the `HTMLBody` property respecting the HTML markup. Even if Outlook handles most issues correctly, this is a good habit to keep the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With OutMail
        .To = "someone@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Country Population Data " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")
        .Display
        
        lastBodyStr = .HTMLBody
        
        Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        wordDoc.Range.PasteandFormat wdChartPicture
        textStr = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc.</b></p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Calibri>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;color:#595959><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor." & _
                "Hendrerit dolor magna eget est.</i></font></p>" 
        
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & textStr & lastBodyStr
                
                
    End With
```

I added a `lastBodyStr` which saves your signature if you have one, changed up your original `.HTMLBody` to be saved as `textStr` and also took out the `& .HTMLBody` and then set the `.HTMLBody` to be in the order it needs to be

Answer (score -1):

When you set up a message body using the Word object model and the `HTMLBody` property in the following way:

```
Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        wordDoc.Range.PasteandFormat wdChartPicture
        .HTMLBody = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc.</b></p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Calibri>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;color:#595959><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor." & _
                "Hendrerit dolor magna eget est.</i></font></p>" & .HTMLBody
```

I'd suggest making sure that you paste the content inside the HTML document not relying on built-in capabilities of Outlook.

That means the `HTMLBody` property returns a well-formed HTML document. And if you need to add something there you need to find the right place for that first. For example, you may need to find the opening `<body>` tag if you need to paste the content in the beginning of the message body or the closing `</body>` tag if you need to paste the content after (in the end).

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow.  Can you please post an example??

Comment: You basically append another HTML document now by doing `<body>... </body>` + `<body>... </body>`.

Comment: are you saying it should look like this: ```<body>wordDoc.Range.PasteandFormat wdChartPicture</body> + <body>... </body>```???

Comment: Nope. In the last line of my code you are concatenating two HTML bodies.

Comment: I'm still not sure what fix you are suggesting.  The code you pasted in your answer is just a copy and paste of a portion of my code.  Do you do this by mistake?? I really appreciate your help with this!!