# how to remove signature inside htmlbody?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

my initial problem was inserting a signature including its format, I have managed to fix it but, i have a problem with an additional signature inserted between the xmailbody1 and the pasted table, see code below:

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim doc As Object, x, signature, xMailBody2, xMailBody1
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Set MyRange = Selection
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display   'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
        
    signature = .HTMLBody

        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        xMailBody1 = "<BODY>Hi Mike, <br><br>This is the first paragraph</BODY>"
                    
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        MyRange.Copy
        doc.Range(x).Paste
        
        xMailBody2 = "<BODY><br>Thank you for your assistance. Please let me know if you require any further information.<br> <br>" & _
                    "Best regards,</BODY>"
        
        .HTMLBody = xMailBody1 & .HTMLBody & xMailBody2 & signature
                    
        .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
        .Subject = "Subject"
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**---current pic---**

[image]

**---desired pic---**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54967553/8422953

Comment: @braX thanks, i have already inserted the signature with its format but my new code cant get the order of text body and table right

Comment: You'll need to save the signature and body text somewhere separate before putting the contents into the `HTMLbody` in the order you desire. Have a look here where I did the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/75797317/1727575

Comment: @Kairu corrected the order but cant figure out how not to show the signature between xmailbody1 and pasted table

Comment: Try setting ‘.HTMLbody = “”‘ before pasting the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved as suggested by @Kairu using `.HTMLBody = ""` before the pasting the table**

open to other solutions better than below code

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim doc As Object, x, signature, xMailBody2, xMailBody1
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Set MyRange = Selection
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display   'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
        
    signature = .HTMLBody

        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        xMailBody1 = "<BODY>Hi Mike, <br><br>This is the first paragraph</BODY>"
        
        .HTMLBody = ""

        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        MyRange.Copy
        doc.Range(x).Paste
        
        xMailBody2 = "<BODY><br>Thank you for your assistance. Please let me know if you require any further information.<br> <br>" & _
                    "Best regards,</BODY>"
        
        .HTMLBody = xMailBody1 & .HTMLBody & xMailBody2 & signature
                    
        .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
        .Subject = "Subject"
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```